# Powershell: formating a double in scientific, using a dot regardless of locale-settings

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, string-formatting

I want do display a double in scientific notation, with 3 decimal places and also three decimals in the exponent-part. Also, I want to display the number using a dot (".") as decimal delimitor (my localization always prints it with a comma). My desired format is like this:

```
1.234e+001
```

How do I do this? All my attempts with

```
echo ( "{0:e}" -f $myDouble )
```

have failed so far... Any hints welcome :)

Comment: What is your result when you call $myDouble.ToString()

Comment: [double]$myDouble = 1000; echo $myDouble.ToString() prints "1000". I want "1.000e+003" in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that is a fascinating trip down locale-settings that I've not had the privilege of doing beforehand, so thank you!  Try this for me:

```
$a = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
[double] $myDouble = 1000
$myDouble.tostring("e3", $a)
```

Comment: +1 because this works, though I believe it'd be more appropriate to use the [`[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) here.

Comment: Great, this works. Meanwhile, I'm using a solution that replaces the "," with a "." using String.Replace. This is even one less line :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`e` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierExponent) to specify the exact format you want regardless of the current culture.  In this case, one digit before the decimal point, three digits after the decimal point, and a three-digit exponent:

```
PS> '{0:0.000e+000}' -f 1000
1.000e+003
```

The problem with that, however, is that the `.` in the above format string will be the localized decimal point (`,` in your case).  There's a few ways you can specify to use a literal `.` character instead...

```
PS> '{0:0\.000e+000}' -f 1000
1.000e+000
PS> '{0:0"."000e+000}' -f 1000
1.000e+000
PS> "{0:0'.'000e+000}" -f 1000
1.000e+000
```

...but now the exponent is wrong and I'm not sure how to work around that.  One way to get it to produce the text you want without any further modification necessary is to force it to use the [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) instead of the current culture:

```
PS> (1000).ToString('0.000e+000', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
1.000e+003
```

Note that this works because in the invariant culture the decimal character happens to be the `.` you want.  If that wasn't the case, or if you just wanted to save some typing, then you can modify the [`NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) for the [current culture's number formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currentinfo.aspx).  Here's an example that changes the decimal character to `!` for the duration of the current PowerShell session/script:

```
PS> [System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator
.
PS> '{0:0.000e+000}' -f 1000
1.000e+003
PS> [System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = '!'
PS> '{0:0.000e+000}' -f 1000
1!000e+003
```

Comment: When I type in the exact same line, I get '1,000e+003'. The comma is the problem. What is the format string that forces PowerShell to use the dot?

Comment: @Sh4pe I did not realize that the decimal point was localized as well, but it turns out [it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPt).  My next thought would be `'{0:0\.000e+000}'`, but then the exponent is incorrect.  What is your local culture (value of `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture`), by the way?

Comment: Mine is de-DE. Thanks for your thoughts, but I already found a solution that fits my purposes :)

Comment: Oh.  Well, sorry to waste your time.  And mine.

Comment: Please don't be sorry, you helped me and I apreciate you efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
echo ( "{0:e3}" -f $myDouble )
```

Comment: [double]$myDouble = 1000; echo ( "{0:e3}" -f $myDouble ) prints the string 1,000e+003. The comma is wrong.

Comment: This is what I get:
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> echo ("{0:e3}" -f [Math]::PI)
3.142e+000

Comment: Yes, exactly this is part of the problem I'm adressing in my question: my 'culture settings' have the comma as decimal separator. I want the dot nontheless...